# what is the difference between getDefaultProps and getInitialState react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new in react js.

```
getDefaultProps () {
    return {
        backgroundColor: 'gray',
        height: 200,
        width: 200
    }
},
```

I've same values for `getDefaultProps` and for `getInitialState` :

```
getInitialState () {
    return {
        backgroundColor: 'gray',
        height: 200,
        width: 200
    }
},
```

What is the logical difference in between both. which should supposed to override or which one will execute first.

Thanks.

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?btnG=1&pws=0&q=difference+between+state+and+props

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**getInitialState**

- The object `**getInitialState()**` Invoked once before the component is
  mounted. The return value will be used as the initial value of
  this.state.

> Note: This method is not available on ES6 class components that extend
>   React.Component. For more information, please read our documentation
>   about ES6 classes.

**getDefaultProps**

- The object `**getDefaultProps()**` Invoked once and cached when the class
  is created. Values in the mapping will be set on this.props if that
  prop is not specified by the parent component (i.e. using an in
  check).
- This method is invoked before any instances are created and thus
  cannot rely on this.props. In addition, be aware that any complex
  objects returned by `getDefaultProps()` will be shared across
  instances, not copied.

Answer (score 5):

**getDefaultProps** is for default props,if you don't inject this prop ,it will work .

**getInitialState** is for ini state,before the component is mounted.

In fact, what matter is the difference between **props** and **state** ,once you understand their differences, their default value's defference is easy to understand.

Answer (score -3):

`getDefaultProps()` is for Properties.

`getInitialState()` is for States.